# How to translate enumerate() to a for loop in Python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, enumerate

I have the following code which finds the index of a guessed number from a long number, however I cannot use enumerate. What would the equivalent for loop look like for this:

```
guess = input()
long_number = ('5666')
a = [i for i, number in enumerate(long_number) if number == guess]
print(a)
```

e.g. Output: if guess = 5, then the output should be [0].

How would you do this using while, for and/or if functions only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply change the list comprehension to:

```
a = [i for i in range(len(long_number)) if long_number[i] == guess]
```

(in your code):

```
guess = input()
long_number = '5666'
a = [i for i in range(len(long_number)) if long_number[i] == guess]
print(a)
```

The output will be identical to yours

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the number as a string and check each digit while using a variable *index* to keep track of the indexes. Here an example:

```
index = 0
for number in [int(num) for num in str(long_number)]:
    if number == int(guess):
        print(index)
    index += 1
```